# Read outlook inbox mails using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I need to read the unread outlook inbox mails using `win32com` library.
I tried:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
print(inbox)
for account in outlook.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print (body_content)
```

I can see my account display name but`body_content` is empty.
Where am I wrong? How can I read all unread mails?

Comment: If you do `for messages in inbox.Items:`, do you see message objects?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, I can see subject of 500+ recent mails. Thanks.

Comment: @TimRoberts : Now I can read inbox, but not recent mails. I can read all yesterday's mail. Is this because of timezone?

Comment: Do you mean "mail I know I received today is not preset", or do you mean "all of the messages have an older timestamp"?  And how do you get any work done with 500 messages in your inbox? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Items.GetLast` is not guaranteed to give you the latest email you see on top of your Outlook inbox. `Items` collection is not sorted in any particular way unless you explicitly sort it (e.g., `messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", true)`).

If you need unread messages, you need to explicitly ask Outlook to give yo unread emails:

```
unreadMessages = messages.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
```

You will then need to loop through the returned restricted collection.